# .mp3's downloading as .mpga on Android. Is this to do with MIME types?

Tags: android, mp3, mime-types, mime

Hi i'm hoping one of you can help me. I've got a small problem. When an .mp3 (with all its id3 information) is downloaded from my site using the android stock browser the file is saved as an .mpga file and all the id3 info is lost.

Is there a way of forcing an .mp3 to download as an mp3? I've looked into this just now and I think this is achieved by setting the correct MIME type. I would just like someones help on how to do this, if indeed this is the correct course of action.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you check the MIME type? like with `curl -I <the_mp3_url>`

Comment: I'm not sure how i'd go about doing this, sorry but where do I type this to check the MIME type?

Comment: @Berns go for "curl" (download it, available at least for linux and windows) and type the command into the terminal...

Comment: I've only a shared server for which I have no console access :(

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Chrome? Star this issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170852